# Unable to change php version in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, localhost, apache2

I am trying to change my php version in my ubuntu 18.04.
i want to change from 7.0 to 7.2.
I have updated the php to 7.2.
changed the php version from `sudo a2enmod php7.2`.

In terminal:

```
$ php --ini
  Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.2/cli
  Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
  Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d
```

In localhost:

```
<?php phpinfo();?>

PHP Version 7.0.30-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
System  Linux linux 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 
06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64
Build Date  May 2 2018 12:44:20
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/7.0/apache2
Loaded Configuration File   (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d
```

In terminal:

```
 php -version
 PHP 7.2.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May  5 2018 
 05:00:15) ( NTS )
 Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
 Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
 with Zend OPcache v7.2.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright 
 (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

I am not able to identify where the issue is.
 after i purge the php 7.0 also does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you try this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Here you can find more:
https://serverfault.com/questions/895746/switch-from-php-7-2-to-7-1-on-ubuntu-16-04-apache

and here:
https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

after this

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

My Apache2 was failing to start since PHP 7.2 was installed, but in my /etc/apache2/mods-enabled folder, I had php7.0 files present. I had to remove them, then **sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.2 --reinstall** to make everything work again.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias setphp="sudo update-alternatives --config php;sudo update-alternatives --config phar; update-alternatives --config phar.phar; a2dismod php*.*;systemctl restart apache2"
```

Put the above alias in the

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

#After the above command just run this command

```
a2enmod php<Your Desired Version> # like, a2enmod php7.4
```

Now you can run command "setphp" from your terminal.